# Configure squid to forward requests to another proxy

Tags: ubuntu, squid, forwarding

I'd like to setup squid on Ubuntu as a forward proxy. The application I'm using only allows requests via unauthenticated proxies, not proxies that require username/password. It's for this reason I'd like to have the application make it's requests initially to a local instance of squid (without needing auth) and then have squid forward the request to my third-party proxy (which needs auth).

Could anyone provide or point me to details of how to set this up?

(Note I don't want squid to intercept all http connections on the server or anything like that, just to listen on some port like 8888 and I'll have my application make specific requests to localhost 8888)

Answer (score 1):

Best I came up with so far is to use `cache_peer` like

```
cache_peer XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX parent 80 0 no-query no-digest login=<user>:<pass>
never_direct allow all
```

to make squid connect to the auth proxy.

It seems to work if I test with `curl -x http://127.0.0.1:3128 ifconfig.me`, but I'm not sure if it's optimal or if any other factors I should consider.